# nmcli ipv4.manual

Tags: fedora, networkmanager, nmcli

I'm having trouble getting Network Manager Command Line Interface to set the IP address method to manual.  Here is the command that I expect to work:

```
[me@computer]$ sudo nmcli connection modify 'Wired connection 1' ipv4.method manual ipv4.addresses 192.168.2.180/24
Error: failed to modify ipv4.method: 'manual ipv4.addresses 192.168.2.180/24' not among [auto, link-local, manual, shared, disabled].
```

Just specifying the ipv4.method command by itself doesn't work either.

```
[me@computer]$ sudo nmcli connection modify 'Wired connection 1' ipv4.method manual
Error: Failed to modify connection 'Wired connection 1': (32) ipv4.addresses: property is missing
```

Setting it to auto works as I expected.

```
[sri@s6000-devel gui3]$ sudo nmcli connection modify 'Wired connection 1' ipv4.method auto
```

The expected final result is to set the BOOTPROTO parameter in the config script.

```
    cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-Wired_connection_1
TYPE=Ethernet
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DEFROUTE=yes
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NAME="Wired connection 1"
UUID=1d578ea5-7164-44b2-xxxx-xxxxxxxx
ONBOOT=yes
HWADDR=E0:3F:49:xx:xx:xx
PEERDNS=yes
PEERROUTES=yes
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  How do I get nmcli to disable DHCP on boot and use a manual ip address instead?

Here is my OS:

```
[me@computer]$ uname -a
Linux me.computer.com 3.18.5-101.fc20.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Feb 2 20:58:23 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Here is the version of nmcli that is installed.

```
[sri@s6000-devel gui3]$ nmcli -v
nmcli tool, version 0.9.9.0-46.git20131003.fc20
```

### EDIT

Trying the version of the command that chexum provided gives the following answer.

```
sudo nmcli conn modify "Wired connection 1" ipv4.addresses 192.168.2.180/24 ipv4.gateway 192.168.2.1 ipv4.method manual

    Error: failed to modify ipv4.addresses: '192.168.2.180/24 ipv4.gateway
    192.168.2.1 ipv4.method manual' is not valid (use ip[/prefix] [gateway]).
```

I bet that the solution is to upgrade to the latest version.  We shall see.

Answer (score 2):

The *property is missing* error suggests it needs more properties changed at once.  There's also a section in the `nmcli-examples(5)` manual showing this message:

```
Do you also want to set 'ipv4.method' to 'manual'? [yes]: yes
```

So I'd rather change all the properties at the same time, and this seems to work for me:

```
# nmcli conn modify "Wired connection 1" ipv4.addresses 192.2.0.100/24 ipv4.gateway 192.0.2.254 ipv4.method manual
```

To revert though, it's easier:

```
# nmcli conn modify "Wired connection 1" ipv4.method auto
```

Perhaps you want to change more of the properties (like DNS, or ipv6 related configuration), so check all the available ones on the interface with:

```
# nmcli conn show "Wired connection 1"
```

Comment: Yeah, I saw that in the manual and other documentation but that's in an interactive mode.  A command line solution is critical.  Now, I tried what you sent me thinking, "bloody hells! its an order of options issue."  Sadly no, I get an error using your version of the command as well.  Specifically, "Error: failed to modify ipv4.addresses: '192.168.2.180/24 ipv4.gateway 192.168.2.1 ipv4.method manual' is not valid (use ip[/prefix] [gateway])."

Comment: so, checxum, what version of nmcli are you running?  "nmcli -v"

Comment: Oh, mine is 1.0.4 much, newer.  Have you tried `ipv4.addresses 192.168.2.180/24 192.168.2.1` as the error message suggests? An RH bug discusses a similar error in a similar version, https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=998929 - from what I can tell, yours is the fixed one as it prints an usage for it.

Comment: Yes, I used the new syntax.  Still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

It will be best if you first create your new connection with `ipv4.address`, `ipv4.gateway` etc.
For example:

```
nmcli connection add con-name New-connection type ethernet ipv4.addresses 192.168.1.23 ipv4.gateway 192.168.1.23 ifname enp0s3
```

After doing this you can modify your connection for `ipv4.method manual`.

```
nmcli connection modify New-connection ipv4.method manual
```

Then you need to run

```
nmcli con reload
```

or

```
reboot
```

Now check whole information about your connection:

```
nmcli connection show New-connection
```

And I bet this will surely work without any error.